# try to send a viewmodel to view

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, controller

I have a asp mvc project :

Model:

```
 public class TeamDto
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserListDto> Users { get; set; }
}
    
    public class AddTeamViewModel
    {
        public TeamDto Team { get; set; }
        public List<UserListDto> AllUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEditTeam(int id = 0)
        {
            var users = await _userAppService.GetAllUsers();

            var view = new AddTeamViewModel { Team = new TeamDto(), AllUsers = users.ToList() };
            if (id == 0) return View(view);

            var team = await _teamAppService.GetTeamById(id);

            return View(new AddTeamViewModel { AllUsers = users.ToList() , Team = team  });
        }
```

View:

```
  <h4 class="m-portlet__head-caption">@(Model.Team.Id > 0 ? "Edit Team" : "Add Team")</h4>
```

I can not undrestand why I get this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Areas_App_Views_Team_AddOrEditTeam.b__22_1()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are posting the value and then trying to send the viewmodel to a view. In this case, try redirecting to action instead of showing the View.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEditTeam(int id = 0)
        {
            var users = await _userAppService.GetAllUsers();

            var view = new AddTeamViewModel { Team = new TeamDto(), AllUsers = users.ToList() };
            if (id == 0) return RedirectToAction("YourViewName",view);

            var team = await _teamAppService.GetTeamById(id);

            AddTeamViewModel teams = new AddTeamViewModel{
                AllUsers = users.ToList(), 
                Team = team
            };

            return RedirectToAction("YourViewName", teams);
        }
```

This will solve your object reference issue.